# Another "Symbol(s) not found for architecture i386" Error - XMPPFramework

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, linker-errors, xmppframework

I just added XMPPFramework to my existing Xcode project.

I think I have done all the required things to build it, but when I try to build, I get linker errors as followings :

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in XMPPvCardTemp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**I have read similar questions** and I know it usually occurs because of not linking a required library or framework with the binary, but I have checked everything I knew that is required ( I also done everything on the documentation : https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/GettingStarted_iOS )

But dependencies and frameworks seem to be linked correctly:

[image: Frameworks]

I'm also sure about the fact that I have added `XMPPvCardTemp.m` to the list of `Compile Sources` :

[image: Compile Sources]

and I'm also sure that I have added it to my target :

[image: Target Membership]

But I still get this error.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the screen shot of the error it seems like  you did not add core location framework . Recheck May be you have missed it.

Also I see that you are trying to run it on simulator. I have seen some frameworks which could be run only on devices

Comment: Is CoreLocation required to run XMPPFramework ?
I will try adding it

Comment: Thank you. I just added and it worked. But I haven't find anywhere that said it is required to link it with CoreLocation ! :)

Comment: I'm glad that it worked for you) documentations is no perfect;)